# How do I get all subcategories of parent categories in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have all parent categories in the `$categories` variable, and all subcategories in the `$subCats` variable. The problem is that, in addition to the subcategories, empty parent categories also fall into the `$subCats` variable. How can you fix this?
[image]

```
public function showForm() 
{
    $subCats = [];

    $categories = Category::where('parent_slug', null)->get();
    foreach($categories as $cats) {
        $subCats[] = Category::where('parent_slug', $cats->slug)->get();
    }

    return view('user.form', compact('categories', 'subCats'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need a loop :

```
$categories = Category::where('parent_slug', null)->get();
$subCats = Category::where('parent_slug', '!=', null)->get();

return view('user.form', compact('categories', 'subCats'));
```

For more performance, you can filter with [whereNull()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-wherenull) method on a collection :

```
$data = Category::get();

$categories = $data->whereNull('parent_slug')->all();
$subCats = $data->whereNotNull('parent_slug')->all();

return view('user.form', compact('categories', 'subCats'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    public function showForm() 
    {
        $subCats = [];
    
        $categories = Category::where('parent_slug', null)->get();
        foreach($categories as $cats) {
           $subCat = Category::where('parent_slug', $cats->slug)->get();
           if($subCat->count()) {
             $subCats[] = $subCat;
           }
        }
    
        return view('user.form', compact('categories', 'subCats'));
    }
```